# Jquery - Carasol build finished and would like advice on best practice / neatening up my code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been building my own carasol over the past few days.

My Jquery is based on tutorials on the web and also from help and advice from SO.

I am not a Jquery guru just an enthusiast and think my code is a little sloppy, hence the post.

here is a link to the working code: http://jsfiddle.net/JHqBA/2/ **(updated link)**

basically what happens is:
if someone hits the page with a # values in the url it will show the appropriate slide and example would be www.hello.com#two, this would slide to slide two

if someone clicks the numbers it will show the appropriate slide

next and prev also slide through the slides.

The question is, is there anything i could have wrote better as i know there is alot of duplicate code.

I understand its a big ask but it would help me learn a little more (i think my code is a little old school)

if anyone has any questions please feel free to ask and ill answer what it does or is supposed to do.

Sluap

***--- Edit ----***

I have made only one aniamtion function now which has got rid of alot of duplicate code.

I have yet to look into **on function** but will do soon.

I would like to know more about the **create a new function, outside of the jQuery ready block** as i cant get this working or quite understand how i can get it to work sorry

any more tips would be great ill carry on working on this project till i am happy with it.

also is there a better way to write:

```
if ($slideNumber == 1) {
    $('#prev').attr("class", "not_active")
    $('#next').attr("class", "active")
}
else if ($slideNumber == divSum) {
    $('#next').attr("class", "not_active");
    $('#prev').attr("class", "active");
}
else {
    $('#prev').attr("class", "active")
    $('#next').attr("class", "active")
};
```

Jquery full:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    ////////////////////////////  INITAL SET UP  /////////////////////////////////////////////

    //Get size of images, how many there are, then determin the size of the image reel.
    var divWidth = $(".window").width();
    var divSum = $(".slide").size();
    var divReelWidth = divWidth * divSum;

    //Adjust the image reel to its new size
    $(".image_reel").css({ 'width': divReelWidth });

    //set the initial not active state
    $('#prev').attr("class", "not_active");

    ////////////////////////////  SLIDER  /////////////////////////////////////////////

    //Paging + Slider Function
    rotate = function () {
        var triggerID = $slideNumber - 1; //Get number of times to slide
        var image_reelPosition = triggerID * divWidth; //Determines the distance the image reel needs to slide
        //sets the active on the next and prev
        if ($slideNumber == 1) {
            $('#prev').attr("class", "not_active")
            $('#next').attr("class", "active")
        }
        else if ($slideNumber == divSum) {
            $('#next').attr("class", "not_active");
            $('#prev').attr("class", "active");
        }
        else {
            $('#prev').attr("class", "active")
            $('#next').attr("class", "active")
        };
        //Slider Animation
        $(".image_reel").animate({
            left: -image_reelPosition
        }, 500);
    };

    ////////////////////////////  SLIDER CALLS  /////////////////////////////////////////////

    //click on numbers
    $(".paging a").click(function () {
        $active = $(this); //Activate the clicked paging
        $slideNumber = $active.attr("rel");
        rotate(); //Trigger rotation immediately
        return false; //Prevent browser jump to link anchor
    });


    //click on next button
    $('#next').click(function () {
        if (!$(".image_reel").is(':animated')) { //prevent clicking if animating
            var left_indent = parseInt($('.image_reel').css('left')) - divWidth;
            var slideNumberOn = (left_indent / divWidth);
            var slideNumber = ((slideNumberOn * -1) + 1);
            $slideNumber = slideNumber;
            if ($slideNumber <= divSum) { //do not animate if on last slide
                rotate(); //Trigger rotation immediately
            };
            return false; //Prevent browser jump to link anchor
        }
    });

    //click on prev button
    $('#prev').click(function () {
        if (!$(".image_reel").is(':animated')) { //prevent clicking if animating
            var left_indent = parseInt($('.image_reel').css('left')) - divWidth;
            var slideNumberOn = (left_indent / divWidth);
            var slideNumber = ((slideNumberOn * -1) - 1);
            $slideNumber = slideNumber;
            if ($slideNumber >= 1) { //do not animate if on first slide
                rotate(); //Trigger rotation immediately
            };
        }
        return false; //Prevent browser jump to link anchor
    });

    //URL eg:www.hello.com#one                  
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    var map = {
        one: 1,
        two: 2,
        three: 3,
        four: 4
    };
    var hashValue = map[hash.substring(1)];
    //animate if hashValue is not null
    if (hashValue != null) {
        $slideNumber = hashValue;
        rotate(); //Trigger rotation immediately
        return false; //Prevent browser jump to link anchor
    };
});
```

Comment: the question would be is there anything i could do better

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @metalfrog, sorry was not aware of this, ill move it ASAP

Comment: @sluap It's all good. Figured it might be a better fit there. :)

Comment: Oh brilliant. I did not know about codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question and answer has been moved over to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/8634/jquery-carasol-build-finished-and-would-like-advice-on-best-practice-neateni/8635#8635**

**1) Separation of Concerns**

Start by refactorring your code in to more granular functions.
You can read more about SoF at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns

Update:
E.g. Instead of having your reel resizing code inline, put it in it's own function, like this:

```
function setImageReelWidth () {
    //Get size of images, how many there are, then determin the size of the image reel.
    var divWidth = $(".window").width();
    var divSum = $(".slide").size();
    var divReelWidth = divWidth * divSum;

    //Adjust the image reel to its new size
    $(".image_reel").css({ 'width': divReelWidth });                            
}
```

This achieves 2 things:

a. First, it groups a block of code that is logically cohesive, removing it from the main code which results in a much cleaner code habitat.
 b. It effectively gives a label to the code block via the function name that is descriptive of what it does, and therefore makes understanding of the code much simpler.

Later, you can also encapsulate the whole thing in it's own "class" (function) and you can move it into it's own js file.

**2) The jQuery "on" function**

Use the "on" function to attach your click events, rather than the "click" function.
http://api.jquery.com/on/
This has the added advantage of also binding it to future elements matching your selector, even though they do not exist yet.

**3) The ready function**

```
// I like the more succinct:
$(handler)
// Instead of:
$(document).ready(handler)
```

But you might like the more obvious syntax.

Those are just a few things to start with.

-- Update 1 --

Ok, StackOverflow is not really suited to a refactoring work in progress, but we'll make do. I think you should keep your original code block in your question, so that future readers can see where it started and how it systematically improved.

> I would like to know more about the create a new function, outside of
>   the jQuery ready block as i cant get this working or quite understand
>   how i can get it to work sorry

I am not familiar with jsfiddle.net, but it looks cool and helpful, but might also be a bit confusing if you don't know what is going on. I am not sure I do :), but I think that script editor window results in a .js file that is automatically referenced by the html file.

So here is an example of a function defined outside of the ready block, but referenced from within.

```
function testFunction () {
    alert ('it works');
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    testFunction();

    // ... other code
});
```

This should pop up an alert box that says, "it works" when the page is loaded.
You can try it for yourself.
Then, once you got that working, you can refactor other logically cohesive blocks of code into their own functions. Later you can wrap them all up into their own javascript 'class'. But we'll get to that.

Comment: perfect thank you ill take a look at the above, not sure what you mean by refactorring your code in to more granular functions. i like obvious syntax as mentioned not a guru just yet

Comment: For example, create a new function, outside of the jQuery ready block, calling it something like setImageReelWidth. Then move your code that figures out the image information and adjusts the reel's width into there. Then you just call that function. It makes for much more readable and understandable code, because the function name is descriptive of what it does. Follow?

Comment: Perhaps add new code blocks as updates on your question with your code after refinements.

Comment: will do struggling with functions outside of the main block and calling them but i should be able to neaten up the code etc. ill update as soon as i have anything, i might need to do some reading again